# Problem with "missing $ inserted" message

Tags: math-mode, equations, align

I've been doing an introductory LATEX course and for one of my assignments I want to write a proof where all the equals signs are lined up. I've seen other questions addressing similar problems but when I tried to adapt the solutions to my problem it hasn't worked. My code is this:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath,}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\title{Writing Assignment 1}
\author{Ewan}
\date{\today}
\begin{align*}
(x+y)^3 &= (x+y)^2(x+y)  \\
&= (x^2+2xy+y^2)(x+y) \text{by expanding out the first bracket} \\
&= (x^3+3x^2y+3xy^2+y^3)  \text{by expanding out the brackets} \\
& \equiv  x^3 +y^3 \mod 3 \text{because for $x,y$\in \mathbb{Z}, $3xy^2+3x^2y$ is a multiple of 3}
\end{align*}
```

Whenever I try and compile this it says that there is a missing $ inserted.
Could someone tell me first what I'm doing wrong and second how I could fix it?
I want the text to be on the same line as the algebra it is next to.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! The `$` after `y` should be moved after `\mathbb{Z}`

Comment: The problem is in your last line, you have `\text{because for $x,y$\in ...` but `\in` and `\mathbb{}` are math mode commands and must be in math mode, you should enclose everything from `x` to `3x^2y` in `$ ... $`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Be sure to

- encase math material inside a `\text` directive in `$...$` delimiters
- insert either a space or a `\quad` as the first item in `\text{...}`

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
(x+y)^3 &= (x+y)^2(x+y)  \\
&= (x^2+2xy+y^2)(x+y) \text{\quad by expanding out the first bracket} \\
&= (x^3+3x^2y+3xy^2+y^3)  \text{\quad by expanding out the brackets} \\
&\equiv  x^3 +y^3 \mod 3 \text{\quad because for $x,y\in \mathbb{Z}$, 
         $3xy^2+3x^2y$ is a multiple of 3}
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I think you left an inter-word space before `\quad` by mistake in your last line of the `align*` environment. Will this not add unwanted space?

Comment: @Au101 - Good eye! I've deleted the extra space (and uploaded a new screenshot).